# go.mod has post-v2 module path at revision v2.0.0

Tags: go

I have a rest api I built in Go with gin that has been working for months now on my local machine running 1.12.1. I decided it was going to a docker deploy so I started building with 1.12.6 when I started see errors during module retrieval. I went back to my local machine, ran running 1.12.1 and ran `go clean -modcache`, now the error is there as well. I've tried regenerating multiple times even editing the `go.sum` file to different versions of `gofight` but I'm lost and run out of ideas.

The output w/error:

```
go: github.com/appleboy/gofight@v2.0.0+incompatible: go.mod has post-v2 module path "github.com/appleboy/gofight/v2" at revision v2.0.0
go: error loading module requirements
```

**go.mod**

```
module go-hybrid-alert

go 1.12

require (
    cloud.google.com/go v0.37.0
    firebase.google.com/go v3.6.0+incompatible
    github.com/Luzifer/go-openssl v2.0.0+incompatible
    github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery v1.5.0
    github.com/antchfx/htmlquery v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/antchfx/xmlquery v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/antchfx/xpath v0.0.0-20190129040759-c8489ed3251e // indirect
    github.com/appleboy/gin-jwt v0.0.0-20190216100112-ca1084e5d5a2
    github.com/gin-contrib/sse v0.0.0-20190301062529-5545eab6dad3 // indirect
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.3.0
    github.com/go-redis/redis v6.15.2+incompatible
    github.com/gobwas/glob v0.2.3 // indirect
    github.com/gocolly/colly v1.2.0
    github.com/kennygrant/sanitize v1.2.4 // indirect
    github.com/kisielk/godepgraph v0.0.0-20181003180210-9a9a3d47fba3 // indirect
    github.com/levigross/grequests v0.0.0-20190130132859-37c80f76a0da // indirect
    github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.7 // indirect
    github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure v1.1.2
    github.com/saintfish/chardet v0.0.0-20120816061221-3af4cd4741ca // indirect
    github.com/temoto/robotstxt v0.0.0-20180810133444-97ee4a9ee6ea // indirect
    github.com/ugorji/go/codec v0.0.0-20190316083543-95c34d148dff // indirect
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190313024323-a1f597ede03a
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20190313220215-9f648a60d977
    google.golang.org/api v0.2.0
    gopkg.in/dgrijalva/jwt-go.v3 v3.2.0 // indirect
    gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8 v8.18.2 // indirect
)
```

**go.sum** (the line for the module in question, posting the whole thing exceeds SO post length)

```
github.com/appleboy/gofight v2.0.0+incompatible/go.mod h1:H/tvof1oZHnZdlBd+AeODZGkk1C+D2na0NXr0iXuZHA=
```

I've also tried adjusting the `go 1.12` statement in `go.mod` for the specific subversions I'm attempting to build with but that had no effect.

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A number of packages were outdated, the main fix was to run the new install command for gin-jwt, `go get github.com/appleboy/gin-jwt/v2`

Ultimately though I just nuked my `go.mod` and `go.sum` and did a fresh sync in Goland IDE. Everything is working on 1.12+